# Facebook Share/Like Button -> News Feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, share-button, facebook-feed

I need a facebook share/like button on my page, that posts my page with picture, title, description etc. into the news feed. I've created one with the Facebook "Like-generator" and bring it succesful on my page, but when I click on "like" my page is not in the news feed, only on my wall.
As a second step I want to activate a form when the user shares the page on facebook. Is it possible to do that? FB.Event.subscribe?

I need a direct share (one-click share) of the page - without click a second time share on: http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=

I found an example of this button I need
http://www.thomashutter.com/index.php/2009/07/facebook-die-10-facebook-seo-tipps-die-jeder-facebook-seitenbetreiber-wissen-sollte/

On this site there is a button called "Empfehlen", when you click on this button, the page will be post on your wall and it will be displayed in the news feed.

Comment: did you ever find a fix to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Like button clicks will post on the users wall 100% of the time; however, facebook uses an algorithm to determine the relevance of the link and that determines the probability of that post appearing on the users news feed. So in other words, not everything you post on your wall will appear on your news feed. This is new, before, everything wall post appeared on the news feed but facebook is now selling space on the news feed to commercial page wall posts so that limits the space for regular pages

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook has rather extensive documentation on how to make like buttons, including a code generator.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Comment: I'vo done that, but when someone likes my site, it won't be displayed in the news feeds, only on my wall!

Comment: So what is the OpenGraph description you've provided?

Comment: I use og:title, og:type, og:url, og:image, og:site_name, og:description and og:admins - On my wall everything will be displayed correctly!

Comment: Hmm. And are you logged in to Facebook as yourself? Note that "your wall" is displayed to others as their newsfeed. Try and log in as somebody else to test.

Comment: I've tested it with another account, but the link will be only displayed when I add a comment in the popup bubble that opens when I click on like.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add a facebook like button on your page. And then you have to set up the open graph meta tags in the `<head>` of your page. These tags allow you to describe the page with a title, a description and an image which will be displayed in the news feed.

These two steps are described here : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: This works for me, but when somebody click on the like Button it won't be displayed in the news feed, only on users wall. I need a Button which posts my site in the news feeds that all of my friends can see the entry.

Comment: Are you sure it's only displayed on the user's wall? I thought it was in the news feed too. You can use the old share button instead, but it's deprecated: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/03/01/p3pc-facebook-share/

Comment: Thanks. I've asked a friend to click on the Button and I saw the entry on his wall, but it wasn't in the news feed! I'll test it in the next minutes and watch if it works now.

Comment: Facebook sometimes takes a few minutes to synchronize its various models. Check again in 10 minutes.

Comment: I tested it. When a user clicks on "like" it won't display in the news feed (after 10 minutes too) but when a user adds a comment (in the little popup bubble that opens) it is in the news feed! Is there a way that this happens automatically? Or is there another meta og: tag for that? Or should I use the <iframe>-version?